# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Object::Country, why can't see model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake-task

I have rails 3.1, I am trying to populate data with seeds.rb
I have a model `Country` which is migrated into a countries table

But it seems that rails can't see Country model from seeds.rb
I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Object::Country

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

my seeds.rb file looks like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

Country.delete_all
```

my Country model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :instructors

end
```

any idea please ?

**EDIT**

I am in development environment, with `config.threadsafe!`