# rake paperclip:refresh not working on heroku

Tags: heroku, paperclip

I have changed my paperclip styles and want to refresh them on heroku. I do as

```
heroku run rake --trace paperclip:refresh CLASS=VenueImage
```

and get the error

```
** Invoke paperclip:refresh (first_time)
** Invoke paperclip:refresh:metadata (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute paperclip:refresh:metadata
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant VenueImage
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.7.0/lib/paperclip.rb:179:in `block in class_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.7.0/lib/paperclip.rb:178:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.7.0/lib/paperclip.rb:178:in `inject'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.7.0/lib/paperclip.rb:178:in `class_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.7.0/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:10:in `obtain_attachments'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.7.0/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => paperclip:refresh => paperclip:refresh:metadata
```

Now given that class `VenueImage` definitely exists.

```
heroku run console

Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> VenueImage
=> VenueImage(id: integer, venue_id: integer, image_file_name: string, 
    image_content_type: string, image_file_size: integer, 
    image_updated_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: Seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828841/production-rake-tasks-dont-recognize-my-models

Comment: I tried the suggestion in link above and it now works. To me this is totally insane. What does threadsafe have to do with the way rake tasks run in the heroku environment?