# Rake Task not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rake-task

I am trying run a Rake Task that insert records in DB, but when i run this rake task, i see this error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Classified`

**Classified** is a model on the DB.

This Rake task work well on my local machine (development and production RAILS_ENV).

heroku not allow this type of rake task?

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Production Rake Tasks Don't Recognize My Models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828841/production-rake-tasks-dont-recognize-my-models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `:environment` on my rake task

```
task :my_task => :environment do
   # do work
end
```

i also add the followind line:

`config.dependency_loading = true`

on production.rb file