# rake aborted! rake not loading environment models 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

Have already looked at this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628830/rake-aborted-uninitialized-constant-objectcountry-why-cant-see-model), at which point I looked at all  of the links in the answer.

Created custom rake task, code looks like this:

```
task :seeding do
    op_a = CoverageDetail.create(option: 'a', privacy_and_website_media: 250000.00, privacy_breach_service: 20000,
                    legal_forensic_cost: 25000.00, call_center_service: 'inc', deductible: 5000.00,
                    credit_monitoring_individuals: 20000, fraud_resolution_service: 5000, regulatory_defense: 100000.00,
                    pci_fines_and_costs: 50000.00, crisis_management_and_pr: 50000.00, foreign_notification: 10000.00)

    op_b = CoverageDetail.create(option: 'b', privacy_and_website_media: 500000.00, privacy_breach_service: 25000,
                            legal_forensic_cost: 50000.00, call_center_service: 'inc', deductible: 5000.00,
                            credit_monitoring_individuals: 25000, fraud_resolution_service: 5000, regulatory_defense: 250000.00,
                            pci_fines_and_costs: 50000.00, crisis_management_and_pr: 50000.00, foreign_notification: 10000.00)

    op_c = CoverageDetail.create(option: 'c', privacy_and_website_media: 1000000.00, privacy_breach_service: 50000,
                            legal_forensic_cost: 100000.00, call_center_service: 'inc', deductible: 5000.00,
                            credit_monitoring_individuals: 50000, fraud_resolution_service: 5000, regulatory_defense: 500000.00,
                            pci_fines_and_costs: 50000.00, crisis_management_and_pr: 50000.00, foreign_notification: 10000.00)

    op_a.save!
    op_b.save!
    op_c.save!
end
```

I have a table called coverage_details I have a model called coverage_detail.rb I have a controller called coverage_details_controller.rb. The class name in the model is CoverageDetail.

**Problem:** Why am I getting `uninitialized constant CoverageDetail`?

This is my first time trying to create a custom rake task to seed a new table in an existing app, or I would just add this info to my db:seed file.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you update title of your question, so that if someone else face this problem he can easily get it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use environment to give it rails environment

```
task :seeding => :environment do
    op_a = CoverageDetail.create(option: 'a', privacy_and_website_media: 250000.00, privacy_breach_service: 20000,
                    legal_forensic_cost: 25000.00, call_center_service: 'inc', deductible: 5000.00,
                    credit_monitoring_individuals: 20000, fraud_resolution_service: 5000, regulatory_defense: 100000.00,
                    pci_fines_and_costs: 50000.00, crisis_management_and_pr: 50000.00, foreign_notification: 10000.00)

    op_b = CoverageDetail.create(option: 'b', privacy_and_website_media: 500000.00, privacy_breach_service: 25000,
                            legal_forensic_cost: 50000.00, call_center_service: 'inc', deductible: 5000.00,
                            credit_monitoring_individuals: 25000, fraud_resolution_service: 5000, regulatory_defense: 250000.00,
                            pci_fines_and_costs: 50000.00, crisis_management_and_pr: 50000.00, foreign_notification: 10000.00)

    op_c = CoverageDetail.create(option: 'c', privacy_and_website_media: 1000000.00, privacy_breach_service: 50000,
                            legal_forensic_cost: 100000.00, call_center_service: 'inc', deductible: 5000.00,
                            credit_monitoring_individuals: 50000, fraud_resolution_service: 5000, regulatory_defense: 500000.00,
                            pci_fines_and_costs: 50000.00, crisis_management_and_pr: 50000.00, foreign_notification: 10000.00)

    op_a.save!
    op_b.save!
    op_c.save!
end
```

The environment gives it rails running environment and Your model CoverageDetail comes in the scene.

thanks

Comment: Bah I knew it was something simple. Thanks a ton that worked perfectly +1 and in 7 min when I can you get the check mark.